# Text in content area within div not overflowing correctly

Tags: html, css

so my issue is for some strange reason I'm having difficulty setting an overflow in the content area. I've tried using max-height and overflow-y: auto in the .window1.content selector but that shrinks the size of the image which I don't want. I just want a vertical scroll wheel to appear without messing up what I've already defined.

```css
.window {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: rgba(20, 19, 43, 1);
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.close-button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  border: 0px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.windowheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(37, 35, 58, 1);
  color: #fff;
  height: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.window1 img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
  align-self: center;
}

.window1.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content h1,
p {
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(171, 168, 168);
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="window1" class="window desktop hidden">
  <div class="windowheader">
    <div id="window1-title">LLLJJJIII</div>
    <button class="close-button" onclick="closeTab(2)"> <div id="circle"></div> </button>
  </div>

  <div class="window1 content">

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Glazed-Donut.jpg/1200px-Glazed-Donut.jpg">
    <h1>Username</h1>
    <p>yes hello congrats you have made it to my website</p>

    <p>this is currently a wip but for the time being will host all of my stuff and will just be a place where I put anything, software projects, 3d projects - anything I find cool.</p>

    <p>since i'm still learning frontend development this website is going to have a lot of changes</p>

    <p>this is supposed to mimic my desktop (even though mine doesn't look like this so get comfortable and enjoy being in my world)</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet should be what you're after. I've added the following CSS to the `.window1.content` selector:

```
  width: 500px;
  height: 370px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

The CSS above defines the space the window  should be and turns on the vertical scrolling of the div.

I've also added some `margin-top` to the image to ensure you can still see the image in the current layout.

```css
.window {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: rgba(20, 19, 43, 1);
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.close-button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  border: 0px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.windowheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(37, 35, 58, 1);
  color: #fff;
  height: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.window1 img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
  align-self: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.window1.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 370px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content h1,
p {
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(171, 168, 168);
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="window1" class="window desktop hidden">
  <div class="windowheader">
    <div id="window1-title">LLLJJJIII</div>
    <button class="close-button" onclick="closeTab(2)"> <div id="circle"></div> </button>
  </div>
  <div class="window1 content">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Glazed-Donut.jpg/1200px-Glazed-Donut.jpg">
    <h1>Username</h1>
    <p>yes hello congrats you have made it to my website</p>
    <p>this is currently a wip but for the time being will host all of my stuff and will just be a place where I put anything, software projects, 3d projects - anything I find cool.</p>
    <p>since i'm still learning frontend development this website is going to have a lot of changes</p>
    <p>this is supposed to mimic my desktop (even though mine doesn't look like this so get comfortable and enjoy being in my world)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="window1">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.window1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.window1.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```